# How to access camera of iPhone using phonegap app

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have a simple application developed for android which takes a photo, accessing the camera of device.
I want the same application to be run on iPhone. For android we write permissions for accessing camera in manifest file. How do you access the camera in iPhone. Where do we need to set up it. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use the Media Capture API in the latest code, or wait for 0.9.6:
http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the camera in iPhone, you can use following code.

```
// Camera

UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imgPicker.delegate = self;

imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;

imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

//[self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];

[objParent presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];

[imgPicker release];
```

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Below are the delegate method for camera.

Delegate Name: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

Methods:

```
#pragma mark UIImagePickerController delegate

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{

    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary

    UIImage *imgCapturePhoto = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [imgPhoto setImage:imgCapturePhoto];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) picker

{

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Cheers

Comment: sorry i did not mention that i am using phonegap. How to use phonegap application to make use of camera..

Comment: thank you. but i am using phonegap.I did not develope single app in objective-c.where should i use this code

Comment: Hi, you can use this code in your buuton click event. And remaining delegate method at it is. Let me know for any queries.

Comment: @Nishant B : When using PhoneGap we cannot write native code i.e. Objective-C. Hence, your code cannot be used.